# In Ready Player One, what would happen if Artemis fell while jumping?

Tags: ready-player-one

In one scene it shows that Artemis earned the second key and jumped from one floating rock to another to get to the exit. What would have happened if she fell off or missed a rock?

Would she die and have to start over? Or would she re-spawn with the key?

Answer (score 4):

It isn't explicitly stated in the book or the film as far as I recall.

If your avatar dies in the game, you lose your possessions and your XP and have to start from fresh again from level 1, owning nothing.  You could assume that a key would be the same.

> Daito lost his position in the book when he was killed, but he was killed in real life.  I can't see any indication of an Avatar being killed and seeing this reflected on the scoreboard.

However, you don't lose your own personal experience/knowledge.  If you did lose your key(s), then you'd still remember how to get them and and catching up again won't take too long.